# Bluetooth Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Xenial Xerus in Asus F553MA

Tags: wireless, sound

Good Evening everyone,
Today I tried to configure my audio bluetooth device after the PC pairing and device, finding a problem with the audio that transmits the PC. Some time ago I had Windows 10 pre-installed in the PC and I had no such problem. The device is designed to also support Linux Ubuntu. The problem that I see is that my computer transmits in mono instead of stereo mode. I also went into the Gnome settings but not change anything even if I change the profile A2DP Sink mode as I had read in various forums. I would like to know if you can do something to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem since Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.  I have a photive speaker that supports both A2DP and headset modes.  It works with my android phone, with the same computer in Windows 10, and with another computer running Fedora 23.  I believe it also worked with Linux Mint on the same hardware.  But it's never worked with Ubuntu Gnome; it connects as a headset, and the A2DP protocol is disabled.

Edit: I just tried the instructions [here](https://sandalov.org/blog/2146/), and they worked for me; my speaker is currently connected in A2DP and playing in high-quality stereo.  However, I have tried them before, and they did not work on previous Ubuntu versions, so your mileage may vary.

This is still less than ideal, because now I will not be able to switch to headset mode to use the microphone.

Edit 2: I spoke too soon.  I just rebooted the machine to see if the changes would stick, and they did not - the headset would not even connect.  I started working through a few of the steps that I've found: I reloaded pulsaudio's bluetooth-discover module, and that didn't work; I then restarted the bluetooth service, and now it works.  So, try this, and see if you get the same results.

```
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

I'm not sure which of these steps is actually solving the problem.  Also, note that I did not kill and restart pulse itself, since that seems to confuse already-running applications.